# Отбор элементов с помощью querySelectorAll и присвоение стиля

Tags: dom, queryselectorall

```js
function handlerClose() {
  var wrapList = document.getElementById('wrap-list'); // присваиваем в переменную 'wrapList' главный обёртывающий элемент с id = wrap-list.
  var elem = wrapList.querySelectorAll('.button'); // присваиваем в переменную 'elem' все найденные элементы button внутри обёртывающего элемента
  elem.style.color = "red";
}
console.log(handlerClose());
```

```html
<div id="wrap-list">
  <div class="box">
    <span class="button">Close</span>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="button">Close</span>
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="button">Close</span>
    <h3>Title 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Почему не срабатывает код? Что-то никак не могу сообразить.

Answer (score 2):

class-ОВ много надо прокрутить в цикле

```js
function handlerClose() {
  var wrapList = document.getElementById('wrap-list');
  var elem = wrapList.querySelectorAll('.button');
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
    elem[i].style.color = "red";
}
handlerClose()
```

```html
<div id="wrap-list">
  <div class="box">
    <span class="button">Close</span>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="button">Close</span>
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="button">Close</span>
    <h3>Title 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что querySelectorAll возвращает [NodeList](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwidqonJ4JDXAhUjQJoKHT_SBMwQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fru%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FNodeList&usg=AOvVaw1GRrDrDIJCR1Qrqxzktk00) - массивоподобный объект. У него нет свойства style.
Это вам не jQuery) Вот так должно сработать:

```js
var wrapList = document.getElementById('wrap-list');
var elems = [...wrapList.querySelectorAll('.button')];
elems.forEach(elem => elem.style.color = "red");
```

```html
<div id="wrap-list">    
    <div class="box">
        <span class="button">Close</span>
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <span class="button">Close</span>
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <span class="button">Close</span>
        <h3>Title 3</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```